# Detecting free function inside a "combined" LLVM IR instruction?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I can easily find free in this IR call instruction with getCalledFunction():

```
call void @free(i8* %10) #4, !dbg !53
```

However, I can't seem to know how to find it in this call instruction:

```
%call7 = call i32 bitcast (i32 (...)* @free to i32 (%struct.Bar*)*)(%struct.Bar* %7), !dbg !56
```

This instruction is combining a BitCast with a call instruction. I am not sure if "combining" is the proper phrase, but nevertheless, how can I detect free here?

I tried dyn_cast to a Bitcast and it isn't. I even used getCalledOperand() first and tried casting the Value I get from it to a BitCast and it still isn't detecting it. I would appreciate any help with this.

Thanks!

Comment: Which doxygen version? It look a bit like assembler, doxygen has no knowledge of assembler. Can you please create a, small, self contained example (i.e. source and configuration settings generated with `doxygen -x`) that allows us to reproduce the problem?

Comment: The first argument to the call is a [ConstantExpr, returned by getBitCast](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ConstantExpr.html#ae79d05dd3d0b05e080e08f8c5c33f880). `cast<ConstantExpr>(foo)->getOperand(0)` will return the free.

Comment: @albert: that's LLVM-IR code, the question has nothing to do with Doxygen. I removed the bad tags now.

Comment: Note: there is still a reference to doxygen in the text.

Comment: @arnt Bingo that did it! Thank you very much!

Comment: @albert I apologize. I thought Doxygen was relevant maybe. I removed it from the text as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@arnt answered this in the comments, so I'm adding the answer for everyone else.

@arnt: The first argument to the call is a ConstantExpr, returned by getBitCast. cast(foo)->getOperand(0) will return the free.